# border container maximum width and height

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

Using Flex 4 AIR, what is the maximum widtha and height I can set for line and the bordercontainer?

```
bc:borderContainer = new borderContainer();
bc.width = 80000;
bc.height = 80000;
```

Comment: More than would be otherwise practical to use.

Comment: Why would you ever have a component at 80000 pixels?!?

Answer (score 0):

I think in Flex 4 the largest size of a component is 16 million pixels with the largest dimension being 8,191 pixels.  This is if you are targeting FlashPlayer 10. This information can be seen when looking at the BitmapData class API.